# What is the use of lambda functions?

Tags: c++, lambda

Can anyone help me understand the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto hello = []() -> void {
        cout << "Hello World";
    };

    // Call the lambda function
    hello();
}
```

What is the use of `auto hello = []() -> void` here?
I don't understand the meaning of the terminating semicolon after the curly brace (line 7)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read it as if it were one line:

```
auto hello = []() -> void { cout << "Hello World"; };
```

`hello` is a variable which holds a lambda that

- doesn't capture external variables (`[]`),
- does not take parameters (`()`),
- returns `void` (`-> void`, this is called 'trailing return type', specifying the return type of the lambda just like you would for an ordinary function. This is actually unnecessary here.), and
- consists of the single `cout` statement within its body.

It isn't actually executed until the next line, where it is explicitly called.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that all that line is doing is assigning the lambda to the `hello` variable.  It doesn't get executed until the call to `hello()` on the next line.

Comment: Also, it is not necessary to specify the return type if it is void, so the trailing return type here is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks, I incorporated your suggestions.

Comment: It's also not necessary to put in the () if they're empty.